# wrap json data separated by commas with quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i go round wrapping a given string separated with commas in jquery with quotes

Say

```
respons_pre =response[0].s_date; //in code
response_pre= 10/01/2015, 10/02/2015, 11/20/2015;
```

so as to be like

```
response_pre2='10/01/2015', '10/02/2015', '11/20/2015';
```

Comment: It's unclear if response_pre is a string or an array. Please clarify this

Comment: response_pre is a string, response alone is the array, so i have extracted the string in the first index of the response array

Answer (score 1):

Just use `replace()` to replace every occurance of `,` with `', '` for this & add quotes in starting & end of string.

```
respons_pre =response[0].s_date;
    var responseString = "\'"+response_pre.replace(/, /g,'\', \'')+"\'";
```

Working Example:

```js
var response_pre= "10/01/2015, 10/02/2015, 11/20/2015";
var responseString = "\'"+response_pre.replace(/, /g,'\', \'')+"\'";
document.body.innerHTML= "Response String: "+response_pre+'<br/>'+"Output String: "+responseString;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you have an array of Date objects, which you would like to transform into a string containing the dates represented in the MM/dd/yyyy format, enclosed with single quotes, joined with a comma and a space.

I would do it this way :

```
respons_pre.map(function(date) { return "'" + date.toLocaleDateString() + "'"; }).join(', ');
```

Explanation :

- map will apply a transformation to each element of the array
- toLocaleDateString transform a date object to a locate string representation (if you want to force en-US format, it can be passed as a parameter)
- we also add the enclosing single quotes in the transformation function
- finally we join the elements of the resulting string array with a comma and a space

Comment: I have tried this:     response_pre=response.map(function(date) { return "'" + date.toLocaleDateString() + "'"; }).join(', ');
Its saying resonse is not a function

Comment: @Alphy I don't know what your response is, but it works in [this simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/r2efaLjo/).

Answer (score 0):

```
response_pre =response[0].s_date;
responseArr = response_pre.split(", ");
responseArrWithQuotes = responseArr.map(function(dateString) {
    return "\'" + dateString + "\'";
});
responseString = responseArrWithQuotes.toString();
```

`responseString` is the result you're looking for.
Please do note that my answer demands that the string `response_pre` separates the dates with `,`, (comma and space), not only a comma.

Comment: Mapping return the transformed array, so pushing the transformed elements into another array isn't needed. It would be however if you used Array.prototype.forEach instead, which just executes the callback and discard a possible return value.

Comment: @AaronGOUZIT yeah, that's my bad. thanks for the comment. I will fix that.